# What does "altri" mean in "che altri facesse"?

Tags: word-meaning

> Io non mancai di ricordargli, che quanto più conosceva, più era tenuto a rimediarvi, e non aspettare che ***altri*** facesse […].
>   —Niccolò Machiavelli

Can anyone explain how *altri* is used there?

Answer (score 7):

It means "other (people)".

Think about sentences like "gli uni e gli altri" or "non fare ad altri quello che non vorresti fosse fatto a te".

In Machiavelli's sentence, though, it is an archaic usage as it refers to a single (undetermined) person instead of a multitude: it says

> non aspettare che altri **facesse** ogni cosa

whereas today it would be correct to say

> non aspettare che altri **facessero** ogni cosa