# "Chi altri poteva aiutarla?": perché "altri" e non "altro"?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, pronouns, interrogatives

> E poi, chi altri poteva aiutarla in quel momento?

In questa frase, scritta nel libro *Non so niente di te* di Paola Mastrocola, l'uso del pronome "altri" ha attirato la mia attenzione. La mia domanda è: perché si usa "altri" invece di "altro"? Sarebbe anche corretto scrivere "chi altro poteva aiutarla?"?

**Aggiornamento:** All'inizio avevo scritto «plurale "altri"» e «singolare "altro"» perché non sapevo dell'esistenza del [pronome indefinito singolare "altri"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/altri/). Tuttavia, siccome il pronome singolare "altri" sembra essere di uso raro, formale e letterario, la domanda rimane la stessa. Cioè, come si esprimerebbe questa stessa idea nel linguaggio comune?

Comment: Non è plurale: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/altri/

Comment: See also http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/what-does-altri-mean-in-che-altri-facesse and http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1807/altro-vs-altri

Comment: @egreg:  Tuttavia, in [questa risposta](http://italian.stackexchange.com/a/1151) si afferma che l'uso di "altri" come pronome singolare è arcaico e che oggi si fa l'accordo al plurale.

Comment: In quel contesto forse; non in questo. Seppure non frequente, è usato.

Comment: @egreg:  "Non frequente" significa che "chi altro" è anche corretto e più usato?

Comment: @Charo In questo caso “chi altri” è la locuzione giusta. Che poi molti dicano “chi altro” è un fatto di cui tener conto.

Comment: È possibile che mi sbagli, ma a me a istinto sembra che la seconda parte di quella risposta sia sbagliata. Se "altri" è inteso come singolare credo che il verbo debba andare altrettanto al singolare (magari non è sbagliato, ma sicuramente è meno chiaro).

Comment: @egreg: Penso che il mio problema fosse che non sapevo che il pronome indefinito singolare "altri" si usasse ancora nell'italiano di oggi. Gli esempi del Treccani mi sembrano tutti piuttosto arcaici. Comunque, mi sembra un argomento molto interessante.

Comment: Ancora più incline a crederlo dopo aver letto gli esempi nel link al Treccani postato da egreg, in tutti gli esempi (anche quelli non necessariamente riferiti ad una forma arcaica) il verbo è al singolare. Per me pluralizzare il verbo cambia il significato, e "altri" diventa da interpretarsi come più persone.

Comment: @kos: Interessante osservazione... Anche in questo esempio il verbo "poteva" è al singolare. Forse quella altra domanda meriterebbe una nuova risposta.

Comment: Sinceramente riterrei anch'io. Dopo guardo cosa dice il Devoto-Oli su "altri".

Comment: Il [dizionario De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/altri) qualifica il pronome singolare "altri" con la marca di uso "LE" che ha [questo significato](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/avvertenze/6): "LE: di uso solo letterario; sono vocaboli usati nei testi canonici della tradizione letteraria e noti a chi ha più dimestichezza con essa. Si considerano canonici i seguenti autori dal Trecento al primo Novecento: Dante, Petrarca, Boccaccio, Poliziano, Ariosto, Tasso, Machiavelli, Parini, Foscolo, Leopardi, Manzoni, Carducci, Pascoli, D’Annunzio, Croce;"

Comment: Dai un'occhiata qui: http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/pronomi-indefiniti_(La_grammatica_italiana). "Altri è un pronome che si usa *soltanto per il soggetto maschile singolare* ed è tipico del registro formale". Quindi "altri" con un verbo plurale non può essere altro che un aggettivo, e quindi quella parte della risposta è sbagliata dato che ci si riferisce al pronome indefinito, a meno che non mi stia perdendo qualcosa.

Comment: @kos: "Altri" plurale non è sempre un aggettivo. Se cerchi il pronome "altro" nei dizionari, si possono trovare esempi del pronome "altri" plurale. Nel Treccani, ad esempio, appare questa frase: "perché dài sempre la colpa agli altri?"

Comment: @kos: Nel De Mauro: "alcuni partirono, altri rimasero in città". Qui appare il verbo in plurale.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33622/discussion-between-charo-and-kos).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ecco quello che ho trovato nel libro *Grammatica dell'italiano adulto* di Vittorio Coletti (Il Mulino, Bologna, 2015):

> Una delle ragioni che possono affrettare il decadimento di una parola grammaticale, quando ne esista un suo succedaneo funzionale, può essere la sua equivocità formale. Prendiamo ancora tra gli indefiniti: *altro/altri/altra/altre*. Nella lingua antica esisteva anche un *altri*  pronome singolare (Dante, *Inf.* V: «s'altri  nol niega») che si è ancora usato fino a qualche decennio fa nello scritto o in testi comunque di buona formalità. Ma oggi non lo si adopera più, evitando equivoci col plurale.
>
> [...]
>
> La stessa ragione che ha messo in crisi l'esistenza di *altri* pronome singolare si ritrova dietro la scomparsa ormai imminente, se non già avvenuta, di *questi* e *quegli* pronomi singolare soggetto (nella lingua letteraria anche complemento): «Questi, che mai da me non fia diviso, / la bocca mi baciò tutto tremante» (Dante); «mentre quegli girava la chiave nella toppa» (Manzoni). La sovrapposizione ai plurali di *questo* e di *quello* ha favorito la caduta in disuso di queste forme.

Quindi, nel linguaggio comune attuale, si usa "altro" invece di "altri" come pronome indefinito singolare.

Aggiungo anche la risposta di [Fausto Raso](https://www.blogger.com/profile/08803191616661954000), giornalista che si è occupato da tempo di problematiche linguistiche, a [questo quesito](https://faustoraso.blogspot.com/2016/01/la-sobrieta.html?m=1):

> Gentile amico, si possono adoperare indifferentemente: chi altro o chi altri, anche se quest'ultimo pronome è preferibile riservarlo al campo letterario.

Secondo la mia esperienza, il pronome singolare "altri" si trova ancora con una certa frequenza in testi di un certo grado di formalità.

Comment: Con "la mia esperienza" mi riferisco alla mia esperienza quattro anni e mezzo dopo aver posto la domanda.

Answer (score 0):

Propongo una spiegazione alternativa, conoscendo la provenienza geografica dell'autrice. "Chi altri poteva..." potrebbe essere semplicemente un piemontesismo. Ad esempio, la domanda "Chi altro c'era alla festa?" inizierebbe in dialetto con "Chi autri a iera..." che *suona* come "chi altri" in italiano ed ha il verbo al singolare.

Comment: Interessante... E in italiano standard si direbbe "chi altro poteva aiutarla?"?

Comment: Secondo me, sì. Ma non sono un linguista, in questo caso vado a orecchio.

Comment: A me non sembra una “spiegazione alternativa”: mi sembra solo che l'italiano “chi altri...” in piemontese si dica “chi autri...”.

Comment: No, è sbagliato: in italiano standard si dice proprio _chi altri_.

Comment: Io sono del sud e non ci vedo alcun particolare piemontesismo nell'uso di *altri*.