# Cosa significa "stracciato" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto:

> Ma non c'è gusto né rischi a fendere oggi questa folla di Toledo **stracciata** e pomposa, attenta solo agli equipaggi ricchi, ai funerali, ai lazzi dei lazzari, alle ceste delle ciambelle e dei mandorlati.

Ho letto tutte le accezioni del [verbo "stracciare" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stracciare/). Comunque, non riesco a immaginare cosa possa essere una "folla stracciata". Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 3):

Prova a considerare insieme i due aggettivi: *stracciata* e *pomposa* indicano due qualità opposte. Immagina un abito lacero e uno lussuoso: sono entrambi "eccessivi", "esagerati". La folla di Toledo, in questa descrizione, è così e non solo per gli abiti che indossa, ma anche (forse, soprattutto) per le cose a cui si interessa.

Comment: Sarà, ma io preferirei *stracciona* in quel contesto.

Comment: *Folla stracciata* è un'espressione usata non solo dalla Banti.

Comment: @ErikvanDoren: Chi altri ([chi altro?](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/6398/chi-altri-poteva-aiutarla-perch%C3%A9-altri-e-non-altro)) usa quest'espressione?

Comment: @Charo, Pasolini per esempio, *L'odore dell'India*

Comment: Non so come mettere un link nei commenti, ma ho appena cercato "folla stracciata" in google books e trovato altri

Comment: @ErikvanDoren clicca su _help_ alla destra del campo di immissione del commento. Comunque [ecco il link](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22folla+stracciata%22).

Comment: Quindi il significato sarebbe che una parte della folla era vestita di stracci?

Answer (score -3):

In questo contesto "stracciata" sta a significare "indignata". Quindi la folla era indignata.

Comment: È una forma dialettica figurativa neo barocca. Le persone come segno di indignazione si strappavano le vesti di dosso "letteralmente". Gesto di indignazione e disprezzo. Perché strapparsi le vesti? Nel periodo diciamo pomposo per rimanere sui vocaboli le persone, per un disgusto tale, indignazione tale, non si limitavano a lavarle le vesti, ma, sempre in forma figurativa, se le stracciavano di dosso. Forma che nel dialetto Napoletano è rimasta.

Comment: Hai qualche fonte?

Comment: Indignata? Non mi pare difendibile senza fonti adeguate.

Comment: hahsahhaha. le consiglio di leggere un po di letteratura neobarocca o rococò. '

Comment: @AntonBlackantonblack_com Dubito che Anna Banti (1895–1985) abbia a che fare con la letteratura neobarocca o rococò.

Comment: @AntonBlackantonblack_com: Quando hai finito di ridere, visto che le tue letture sono tanto migliori delle nostre ci trovi un paio di passi in cui è esplicito l'uso che dici?